# WPF Audio Player using MediaElement sometimes lags

Tags: c#, wpf

this is the source code for the audio player:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DispatcherTimer timer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mPlayer.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        mPlayer.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        mPlayer.MediaOpened += mPlayer_MediaOpened;
    }

    void mPlayer_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            TimeSpan ts = mPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
            SeekSlider.Maximum = ts.TotalSeconds;
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            SeekSlider.Value = mPlayer.Position.TotalSeconds;

    }

    private MediaElement mPlayer = new MediaElement();

    private void ButtonOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                timer.Start();
                mPlayer.Source = new Uri(ofd.FileName);
                mPlayer.Volume = VolumeSlider.Value;
                timer.Start();
                mPlayer.Play();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void ButtonPlay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mPlayer.Play();
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void ButtonPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mPlayer.Pause();
        timer.Stop();
    }

    private void ButtonStop_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        mPlayer.Stop();
    }

    private void SeekSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
            mPlayer.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SeekSlider.Value);
    }


    private void VolumeSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
            mPlayer.Volume = VolumeSlider.Value;
    }
}
```

I don't know why it has sudden lags. Please help me in finding the problem. 
If you think that MediaElement is not appropriate for playing different kinds of audio files. Please suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SeekSlider_ValueChanged event was firing too often. so that was causing some lag.

So i solved the problem using the Thumb.DragCompleted event. After this the playback is pretty smooth.